# Set Padding of TextView depending on Content height of TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-view

I currently have a textview with a paddingBottom of 20dp.
I want to reduce this padding if the text within the textView is long enough to otherwise get cut off at the bottom.

Here's a diagram illustrating the behavior I want:
[image]

However, I'm not sure where to call setPadding().
Can someone recommend me an approach for getting this behavior of a dynamic bottom padding?

Comment: why don't you use specific height for that? or even use max lines?

Comment: Hi Saif, I'm not sure I understand your suggestion, and I think my original question was poorly described. I've updated my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom Layout that contained my textView, and overrode its onMeasure() method. The custom layout was set with height='wrap_content'.

The system passes in the available height to this layout's onMeasure() method. So here, I measured my child textView's height with

textView.onMeasure()
int preferredHeight = textView.getMeasuredHeight()

If its preferred height was larger than what my custom view had available to it (minus the bottom padding), I removed the bottom padding with setPadding(). Otherwise, I added the padding.